# Inversion of $z$-transform using partial fraction decomposition

Tags: inverse, signal-processing, partial-fractions, z-transform

I want to inverse a $z$-transform of this general form
$$X(z) = \frac{b_0 + b_1z^{-1}+\cdots+b_Mz^{-M}}{a_0 + a_1z^{-1}+\cdots+a_Nz^{-N}}$$
where $M$ < $N$. In order to do this, I use partial fraction decomposition.
I think there is two equivalent ways to go :

1. Directly find the the coefficient of the partial fraction decomposition and then find $x[n]$ ;
2. Rewrite $X(z)$ as
   $$X(z) = (b_0 + b_1z^{-1}+\cdots+b_Mz^{-M}) \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{a_0 + a_1z^{-1}+\cdots+a_Nz^{-N}}}_{Y(z)}.$$
   Then we can find the partial fraction decomposition of $Y(z)$, find $y[n]$ and then, using linearity and the fact that $z^{-a}Y(z) \leftrightarrow y[n-a]$, find $x[n]$.

These two methods seem identical to me. However, in some cases, it seems they lead to different results.

So here is my question, are these two methods 100% equivalent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. they are 100% equivalent. Even though, it might appear that the two methods result in two different solutions, but in fact they are identical but have different **representations**. Let me give you an example. Consider this following $z$-transform:
$$H(z)=\frac{\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}}{(1-z^{-1})(1-\frac{1}{2}z^{-1})}$$
Using two methods give the following two partial fractions:

1. $$H_1(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}}$$
2. $$H_2(z)=(\frac{1}{2}z^{-1})(\frac{2}{1-z^{-1}}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}})$$

The inverse $z$-transform for two methods are:

1. $$h_1[n]=u[n]-(\frac{1}{2})^nu[n]$$
2. $$h_2[n]=u[n-1]-(\frac{1}{2})^nu[n-1]$$

As it is clear $h_1[n]$ and $h_2[n]$ have the same form except for $n=0$. But $h_1[n=0]=0$, so they are identical.